# Java - Eclipse Issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run the following code in eclipse

```
public class MyTry
{
    public static void main(){ 
        System.out.println("I am Working");
  }
}
```

The code is in the `Project\src` folder . I can see that the class file has been created in the `Project\classes` . But when I run the code I am getting the error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: Is there more than this? It looks like there is a reference to a class named "Hello" in your trace.  Also, you need `String[] args` as a parameter in your main method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears *likely* that that you are running a previous run configuration for a class that no longer exists, hence the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Add a `String` array argument to the `main` method of the class `MyTry` so that the application may be run in `Eclipse`.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
```

Ensure that the class name in Eclipse matches the fully qualified classname for `MyTry` in the run configuration.

Comment: Thanks. It does work now  . But can you kindly point out how adding the string argument makes it work ?

Comment: A class cannot be run if it its signature doesnt match exactly what is expected by the JVM and Eclipse will not allow you to run it. I _suspect_ what was happening was you were running the previous run config which was for the class `Hello` (which seems to be deleted now)

Comment: @misguided if it works now and answers your original question you should accept Reimeus's answer.

Comment: @Reimeus that is correct . I was using the hello class before.

Comment: Apologies , I don't work in java . I keep coming back to use in once every year or so , so kinda forget the eclipse - java basics. Clearly the votedowns show me that this was a very basic question ;)